# C'è in italiano un'espressione equivalente a "peso el tacon del sbrego"?

Tags: idioms, phrase-choice

"***Peso el tacon del sbrego***", ossia "*è   peggio il rattoppo dello strappo"*.

In Veneto questa espressione viene usata quando si vuole significare che il rimedio è peggiore del fatto che si voleva rimediare.

Quale l'espressione in lingua italiana che più si avvicina a questa dialettale?

Comment: O “del buso”, secondo varianti locali.

Comment: Direi semplicemente “è peggio il rimedio del male”. O cercavi qualcosa di più espressivo? Su un dizionario di modi di dire trovo anche il detto, di significato simile, “è peggio il puntello della trave”.

Answer (score 2):

Forse l'espressione  "cura peggiore della malattia"  ?

Answer (score 1):

Fino a dieci secondi fa, avrei detto che in italiano si dice "toppa peggiore del buco"; però non sono troppo lontano dal Veneto, magari è un regionalismo.

Comment: Confermo di aver sentito spesso quest'espressione anche nel Nord Ovest